# What is the meaning of 'join' in thread (VC++2010)?

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++, c++-cli

I read my teacher's code, but I don't understand. Could anyone please tell me the join here mean?

```
    AddTask ^task1 = gcnew AddTask();
AddTask ^task2 = gcnew AddTask();
AddTask ^task3 = gcnew AddTask();

// First Method
Thread ^thread1 = gcnew Thread ( gcnew ParameterizedThreadStart( task1, &AddTask::Add ) );
Thread ^thread2 = gcnew Thread ( gcnew ParameterizedThreadStart( task1, &AddTask::Add ) );
Thread ^thread3 = gcnew Thread ( gcnew ParameterizedThreadStart( task1, &AddTask::Add ) );

thread1->Start("First");
thread2->Start("Second");
thread3->Start("Third");

thread1->Join();
thread2->Join();
thread3->Join();
```

Comment: Is he using a textbook or some reference from where he devises his lectures and code samples?

Comment: @luis.espinal. No note, no book

Comment: that's bad (on him, your professor.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx) function blocks the calling thread until a thread terminates, while continuing to perform standard COM and SendMessage pumping.

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx
```

Comment: Does it mean that thread3 won't begin before thread2 finishes? Does it mean that thread2 won't begin before thread1 finishes?

Comment: @Marco: No, it means that the main thread (the thread that started thread1, thread2 and thread3) won't be able to continue execution until all of them finish.

Answer (score 1):

.Join pauses the thread or Blocks the calling thread until a thread terminates.

ParameterizedThreadStart means that there is a parameter used in the thread

```
thread1->Start("First"); //''as you see there is a parameter: First,Second,Third
thread2->Start("Second");
thread3->Start("Third");

//''The threads starts at the same time and terminate at the same time
thread1->Join();
thread2->Join();
thread3->Join();
```

[link of thread->Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.join.aspx)

[link of ParameterizedThreadStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx)